# Parent / Pin multiple objects to each vertex of a different object?

Tags: modifiers, vertices, constraints

I've created **200 objects** (empty plain axes) and arranged them in a grid.

I also made a **200-vertex plane** object and gave it the **Wave** and **Simple Deform** modifiers.

[image: move objects to vertices]

Is it possible to "pin" or parent each empty object to each individual vertex in the plane so that they move with the waves? Thanks.

**File:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

**I've realized its possible to achieve a similar result by:**
**1.** Selecting both an empty and the plane mesh;
**2.** Going into Edit mode and selecting a vertex of the plane;
**3.** Pressing CTRL + P to parent the empty to 1 vertex of the plane.

[image: parent empty to vertex]

**The issue with this is that I would have to repeat the process for all 200 empties and vertices.**

[image: example]

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to the empties to follow the surface only on the Z axis, may be you better use the Shrinkwrap constraint in Project mode on the empties. You can even copy it to the others.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using the Shrinkwrap constraint on project mode on the empties and and tried targeting the plane object, then a vertex group for the plane object but unfortunately it did not work. I'm still not very experienced with Blender, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Either way, I've found a possible solution (not perfect) which I've added to the post above